# Selenium ChromeDriver is unable to locate element if connected through VPN on macOS

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a problem with with the Selenium WebDriver running on macOS. If I connect to the internet through VPN (Mullvad VPN) ChromeDriver (86.0.4240.22) is unable to locate elements - in my case by using .FindElement(By.CssSelector(...)). The code works fine when I shut down the VPN client and connect to the network "normally". I declared the driver in this way:

```
IWebDriver driver;
var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
driver = new ChromeDriver(outPutDirectory);
```

Is there a way to use the ChromeDriver when my laptop is connected to the internet through a VPN?

EDIT: The case looks as described: I have an app where the first action that is performed by Selenium is to find an element. If I start the app when my computer is NOT connected to the internet through an VPN the whole app works as expected. However, if I connect my laptop to the internet through a VPN ChromeDriver starts normally, but as soon as it tries to perform it's first action the app crashes and I get such an error:

```
Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="emailOrPhone"]"}
```

I tried it also with other websites and the same problem happens until I turn the VPN back off. If I manually connect to the website in Chrome when my laptop is on VPN the website also works.

Comment: What you mean by cannot find element is the website opening properly .?

Comment: The website opens properly, I tried it also with other websites. The problem is that when I disconnect my computer from the VPN, ChromeDriver does everything what it is programmed to, but when I start the VPN the same code fails on the same website. In my case the first action that Selenium is doing is to find an element. On VPN I get "Unhandled exception. OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[name="emailOrPhone"]"}" exception, but then I disconnect from the VPN and start the app again the element is visible.

Comment: when you are connnected to vpn are you able to access the website manually ( not through script)

Comment: Yes, I am able to access the website manually and even use the element that is somehow not visible for Selenium